# how to exclude url mapping in filterRegistrationBean in spring mvc?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlet-filters, url-mapping

I have `Spring 4.0 application` that does not use `web.xml`.
I have the following `webApplicationIntializer` in the spring project.

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {


    public static final String MAPPING_URL = "/*";

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        WebApplicationContext context =new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));


        servletContext.addFilter("counterMetricsFilter", new DelegatingFilterProxy("counterMetricsFilter")).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null,
                false, MAPPING_URL);


        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(
                context));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping(MAPPING_URL);

    }
}
```

I want the filtered to be applied to the following pattern.

`"/v[1-9][0-9]*}"/*` everything except `/v[1-9][0-9]*}"/foobar;`

That is, the following will have `filters` applied

```
/v2/helloworld
/v21/dummy
```

but the following `url` patterns should be ignored

```
/foo/bar
/v2/foobar
/v21/foobar
```

That is the `url` match start with `v{2...}` followed by anything except `foobar` for the `filter` to be applied.

Thanks

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution in the meantime?

Comment: nope. I did not. if you find one, please update with answer